# How do I insert a script variable into a regex string?

Tags: shell

I'm writing a script that is trying to insert a directory name into a pax command and I'm not sure how to get the syntax correct.  This is what I'm trying, but it seems to be treating the $DIRNAME as part of the regex string.

```
DIRNAME=$(tar -tvf $1  | head -1 | sed -e 's:^.* \([^/]*\)/.*$:\1:')
pax -r -f $1 -s'/$DIRNAME\/upload\///'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using double quotes rather than single quotes when calling pax:

```
DIRNAME=$(tar -tvf $1  | head -1 | sed -e 's:^.* \([^/]*\)/.*$:\1:')
pax -r -f $1 -s"/$DIRNAME\/upload\///"
```

In several shells (eg bash and sh), $variables only get expanded when they occur in double-quoted strings, not single-quoted strings.

---

E.g., the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIRNAME=$(echo 'hello')
echo "Single quotes around regexp:"
echo 'hello world' | sed 's/$DIRNAME/hi/'

echo "Double quotes around regexp:"
echo 'hello world' | sed "s/$DIRNAME/hi/"
```

Generates the output:

```
Single quotes around regexp:
hello world
Double quotes around regexp:
hi world
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  The problem is that $DIRNAME is not echoing the contents of DIRNAME, but just inserting the text string $DIRNAME itself into the regex string.

Comment: What shell is the script being run in?  bash?  tcsh?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it again and the error I got was with the pax command, not the $DIRNAME once I double quoted it.  I'm using bash.

Comment: try leaving a space between -s and its regex arguments